# How do I get my button actionListener to count the number of times someone clicks?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
public class Button {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numClicks = 0;

        JButton button1 = new JButton ();
        button1.setText("1 click = 1 dollar for animals you love");

        JFrame god = new JFrame ();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        god.getContentPane().add(button1);
        god.add(button1);       
        god.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        god.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to make the actionlistener count the number of times the button is clicks? Im a noobie coder (3 months) and Im really stuck on this

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for working examples. The example will show you 1) how to better structure your code 2) how to create the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread 3) how to use other Swing components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ActionListener to you button.

```
button1.addActionListener(new MyActionList()); 
//MyActionList is an object which implements ActionListener
```

In your case is the same object.

```
//---implements ActionListener---
public class Button implements ActionListener{

    private int clickCount;

    public Button() {

        clickCount = 0;

        JFrame god = new JFrame ();
        god.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

        //if you don't do this, your program still running, even if you click on X.
        god.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        god.add(panel);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("1 click = 1 dollar for animals you love");

        //here we add ActionListener
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        //'this' refer to the current object. In our case 'new Button()' from 'main'...
        //...which has implemented ActionListener.

        panel.add(button1);

        god.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Button();

    }

    //Override from Interface ActionListener and...
    //...here describe what happend when button was pressed.
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        clickCount++;

        System.out.println(clickCount);

    }


}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on the MyApp as in my code it shows an error
It says MyApp can't be resolved as a type and I'm a little confused on why that is and how it works.

Comment: @Pcnurick `MyApp()` is a constructor. Constructor need to have the name of the class. In your case `Button()`. It was my wrong. I'm sorry.

Comment: Its fine bro I need to know this stuff anyway. Thanks for the advice.